# why progress bar fit the screen width ?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I wrote below method to show progress bar but the progress bar rounded by  white box fits the screen width and i do not know why.

```
public void showProgressBar() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    ProgressBar pbar = new ProgressBar(activity, null,
            android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLargeInverse);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 50);
    pbar.setLayoutParams(params);
    builder.setView(pbar);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar = builder.create();
    progressBar.show();
}
```

when execute the above method the progress shown as this image.

[progress bar problem](http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/1427/progressd.jpg)
How i can solve this issue?

Comment: Why not use a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)?

Comment: I do not need any text beside the progress wheal and if i used ProgressDialog it will fit the screen width also as the right of progress wheel reserved to dialog message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by stupid way but it works fine at me.

```
public abstract class AbstractScreen implements IActivity {

protected Response response;
protected FragmentActivity activity;
private CustomProgressDialog progress;

public AbstractScreen(FragmentActivity activity) {
this.activity = activity;
}

public abstract void loadScreen();

@Override
public void preExecution() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void postExecution(Response response) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 public void showProgressBar() {


 progress = new CustomProgressDialog(activity);
 progress.show();
 }

 public void closeProgress() {
 progress.dismiss();
 }

 public FragmentActivity getActivity() {
 return activity;
 }

 private class CustomProgressDialog extends Dialog {

 private Context context;

 public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
 super(context);
 this.context = context;
 loadScreen();
 }

 public void loadScreen() {

 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 setContentView(R.layout.progress);
 setCancelable(false);

 }

 }
 }
```

add this layout file also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
>

<ProgressBar
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
 android:id="@+id/progressbar"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:max="100"
 />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `ProgressDialog` and no, it doesn't fit the screen width.

```
ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(activity);
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
```

This should give you what you want.

Do this:

```
ProgressDialog pd;//declare as a global variable
public void showProgressBar() {
pd=new ProgressDialog(activity);
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
```

}

Dismiss the `ProgressDialog` wherever you want later.

Comment: +1 Using a `ProgressDialog` will also mean it's pretty much guaranteed to look correct on a variety of devices. Or at least, better than putting it together yourself like in the question's example.

Comment: i tried a lot of methods to get just a centered spinner in the screen  but i failed to get my target as every time the spinner rounded by white area and i do not know the reason of this. by the way the above code gives me the same as i tried before and thanks you for your response.

Comment: You're setting the linear layout to a certain width and height.

Comment: yes i tried it on another emulator and on real devices. but i solved it by work around as below. Thanks for you help.